# Android/Java: java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

Tags: java, android, exception, serversocket

I have a implemented a server socket on my app. My application has two activities, the first is used only for show some informations to the user and to start the second one.
The second activity contains the functionality of the app and the server socket.
Now, i'm always receiving the error in the title of the topic using these steps:
It is always generated if i do these steps:
1. Launch the application  2. Start the second activity  3. Come back to the first activity  4. Go again to the second activity (the app enter in the last catch exception) of the code that i have inserted here below.

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try{
            ServerSocket parent = new ServerSocket();
            parent.setReuseAddress(true);
            parent.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SERVERPORT));
            if ( SERVERIP != null){
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + ip_address_conversion + ":" + SERVERPORT);
                    }
                });

                while (true){
                    Socket client = parent.accept();
                        //do something
                    }
            } else{
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    serverStatus.setText("Error undefined");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is how can avoid this error or fix it.
I have already checked this answers, but in my case doesn't help.
- [java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694002/java-net-bindexception-bind-failed-eaddrinuse)
- [Android ServerSocket EADDRINUSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735032/android-serversocket-eaddrinuse)
- [Android DatagramSocket error message: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568066/android-datagramsocket-error-message-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use)

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to create server socket every time you launch second activity? I suggest you to move your 'server socket logic' into [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and declare ServerSocket reference as static field. In that case you always can manipulate socket state by sending appropriate intent with custom actions(something like 'START_SERVER', 'STOP_SERVER', etc).

Comment: The app should launch the second activity only one time, but if the user click for example the back button of the device for error, in this case the app need to go to the second activity another time. So the server socket is created in a really lower number during the use of the application. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. I will keep it in consideration for the future.